# Acquire template based class Dictionary from MONO?

Tags: c#, c++, mono

No questions if I get classic type like System.String:

```
clsString = mono_class_from_name(image_mscorlib, "System", "String");
```

But when I try to reach template based class like Dictionary it fails:

```
clsDictionary2 = mono_class_from_name(image_mscorlib, "System.Collections.Generic", "Dictionary"); NULL!!
clsDictionary3 = mono_class_from_name(image_mscorlib, "System.Collections.Generic", "Dictionary<TKey,TValue>"); also NULL
```

How to get that to work and get Mono Dictionary class in C++ mono wrapper code. I looked at the MONO library and found that there is Dictionary'2 type in it and I can get it:

```
clsDictionary1 = mono_class_from_name(image_mscorlib, "System.Collections.Generic", "Dictionary`2"); not NULL, pointer
```

But how to instantiate `Dictionary(int, int)` or `Dictionary(object, object)`? Is it correct that I should dig `Dictionary'2` or `IDictionary(??)` and look for corresponding `.ctor(int, int)` or `(object, object)` ?

---

Just a short update for those who are also interested in this question (obj_Instance - a pointer to some .NET object which encapsulates PFILED member obj - Dictionary<,> ptr_DictObj):

```
ptr_DictObj = mono_field_get_value_object(pDomain, pfield, obj_Instance); 
char* cls = (char*)mono_object_get_class((void*)ptr_DictObj); 
char* name1 = (char*)((char*)cls + 0x30); 
char* namesp1 = (char*)((char*)cls + 0x34); 
Log("name1=", name1); 
Log("namespace1=", namesp1);
```

And the answer is `name1=Dictionary'2, namespace1=System.Collections.Generic`.

So it is really `Dictionary'2` class but I still cannot cast `ptr_DictObj` to `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2`. Sudden crash in `mono_object_castclass_mbyref` kills all my dreams to proceed =)))

```
void* obj_Dictionary = mono_object_castclass_mbyref(ptr_DictObj, clsDictionary);
```

---

Just found the reason of that crash.

```
clsDictionary = mono_class_from_name(mono_get_corlib(), "System.Collections.Generic", "Dictionary`2");
```

`clsDictionary` is different than obtained "cls" in runtime. When I try cast `ptr_DictObj` to `clsDictionary` it fails, but succeeded for "cls" typecast.